# Flutter: How to make a widget disappear after a few seconds?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-test

I wanted to make my widget disappear after a few seconds, but it keep getting stuck on waiting.

```
if (unread != 0 && (getMessageObjects.length - count) == unread - 1) {
          _groupedMessages.add(
            FutureBuilder(
              future: Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 500)),
              builder: (c, s) => s.connectionState == ConnectionState.done
                  ? Container(
                      child: Chip(
                        label: Text('Finished'),
                      ),
                    )
                  : Center(
                      child: Chip(
                        label: Text('${unread.toString()} unread messages'),
                      ),
                    ),
            ),
          );
          // reset
        }
```

The _groupedMessages is a List. I have no idea if there are other ways, but please let me know if there are.

Comment: Looks like not a good code, in between why you are making such list of FutureBuilder?

Comment: to display an indicator of how many unread messages they have. The list is List<Widgets>, to be displayed in a listview.builder. The List of widgets contains MessageObjects widgets and by getting the number of unread messages, using the count of unread messages as an index, a new FutureBuilder widget for indicating where the unread messages start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks odd but we need to see the rest of the code.

First thought, are you certain that the future  isn't being constantly recreated and hence doesn't have a chance to complete?

It also seems odd that you are going to show a message indicating the count for 500ms then hide it.

Also why the artificial delay?

I'm guessing you need to fetch the count from a server in which case the future should contain the call to the server and complete when the results are returned.

I would the expect the UI to show a message 'fetching messages' and then change to 'unread messages x' once the fetch completes.

But these are just guesses given the limited amount of context you have provided.